# Is it possible to use compile with MSVC without having Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, msbuild, visual-studio-2012

At my work we are trying to use a standalone repository, meaning that our repo contains the source of course but also the dependencies and the build tool chain. By build tool chain I mean all the tools that are needed to build our application. But the only exception is Visual Studio : to be able to compile our c++ parts, we need to install the entire environment and this is not really convenient. So I was wondering : Would it be possible to compile a c++ application without having VS installed ? But only some kind of build tool chain package ?

I investigated a found out the MSBuild tool which is now part of the VS package but which can be also downloaded alone ("Microsoft Build Tools 2013"). But this does not sontain the MSVC compiler, so it would not help me...

Would it be possible to manually copy the compiler to be able to do this ? Has anyone ever done that ?

Thanks

Roland

Comment: It used to be possible, the Windows SDK (which you always need) used to include the compiler.  Not anymore, you'd have to use an old version.  I think 7.1 was the last one, not entirely sure.  You of course never want to have a mismatch between the version you use in the build machine vs the one that the devs use.  C++11 made sure that you'll have nothing but grief.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. One possibility is copy the cl.exe (VS_FOLDER/bin/architecture) and all its dependencies.

[Compiling a Native C++ Program on the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx)

Another strategy consists in downloading Microsoft Windows SDK:

[Download Microsoft SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

Best regards