# How to install the MSVC compiler for C++ without Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, winapi

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code for C++, but I want to use the MSVC compiler.

[image]

Is there any way to install the MSVC compiler without installing Visual Studio ?

I tried installing Windows SDK according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24039337/7134737)

but unfortunately the Visual C++ compilers are greyed out.

[image]

What can I try next?

Comment: From that picture when you see "Microsoft Visual c++ 2010"  it's got to be the wrong download for 2023.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the Build Tools for Visual Studio package.

Go here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Scroll down to the "All downloads" section and look under the subheading, "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022".

> These Build Tools allow you to build Visual Studio projects from a command-line interface. Supported projects include: ASP.NET, Azure, C++ desktop, ....

Here's the direct link: https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_BuildTools.exe

The Build Tools distribution is meant for build servers, VMs, or command line build environments where the GUI can't be practically installed.  If you're just trying to compile under VS Code, just install the Visual Studio Community edition.